# Vim: What does a double quotation mark mean at the beginning of a command?

Tags: vim

For example when I write a macro command to editor from register `r` with

```
"rp
```

What does that quotation mean?

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The double quote indicates that the next character is the name of a register. So the command `"rp` means: "from the named register `r`, paste text."

Sort of related, a single quote indicates that the next character is an address. So, for example if you navigate to some line in the file and press <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, you've "marked" the address as `a`. You can then refer to that line with `'a`. The command `'a` will  jump to the line marked as `a`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big help. I tried out the `ma` command also. It's pretty nice. On mine though I don't need to type the `g` to go, it just jumps with `'a`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; updated. If you mark more than one line, you can also use commands like `:'a,'bd`, where the `:` puts vi into command mode, and `'a,'bd` deletes all the lines from `a` to `b`. My favorite usage is `:'a,'bs/pattern/replacement/g`, which substitutes the `pattern` regex with `replacement` everywhere in the lines from `a` to `b`.

Comment: That's "register", not "buffer".

Answer (score 3):

@AdamLiss already explained the meaning of `"rp`, but I think you can learn more from Vim online manual.

For the explanation of `p`, you can run `:h p` in Vim; for the introduction of `["x]`, you can run Vim command `:h [quotex]`. And for general help of Vim, just run `:h`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer on the help file. I'll put that in Anki.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, voteup the answer that you think is helpful is a better way to say 'thank you' :-)